# How to Update SQLServer Query with JS variables instead of PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I have this Query, to update two date field "Datum" with the simple date from today and Testende with the current date rounded to 30 or the last date from the database. depend on decision in the if else clause:

```
 $stop = $connection->prepare("WITH UpdateTestende AS (
  SELECT TOP 1  * from MasterarbeitDB.dbo.Testergebnisse 
  WHERE TestaufstellungID = :TestaufstellungID
  ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC 
)

update UpdateTestende 
set Testende = // JS Variable Datum,
Datum = :Testdatum");



                $stop->execute(array(':TestaufstellungID' => $TestaufstellungID, ':Testdatum:' => $Testdatum));
```

I want to Update "Testende" from the DB with the following variables i get from decision javascript functions:

```
<?php
if($_GET['Einheit'] == 'Zyklen'){
?>  
<script>
/* Funktionen um Zeiten für Zyklen aus DB.TesterCycleCount zu erhalten, bzw. für Test und Stunden das aktuelle Datum gerundet auf 30 Minuten */ 
$(document).ready(function(){

var TesterID = "<?php echo $_GET['TesterID']; ?>"; /* value der Tester erhalten */ 

        $.ajax({ /* AJAX aufrufen */
            url: 'ma_get-TesterID.php',
            type: 'get', /* Methode zum übertragen der Daten */
            data: {TesterID:TesterID}, /* Daten zu übermitteln */
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){ /* Die zurückgegebenene Daten erhalten */


                    var CID = response['CID'];
                    var Datum = response['Datum'];



                }
            }
        });


</script>
<?php
}elseif($_GET['Einheit'] == 'h' || $_GET['Einheit'] == 'Test'){
    ?>
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function(){


var jetzt = moment();
jetzt.seconds(0);
jetzt.milliseconds(0);
var minuten = jetzt.minutes();
var minutenToAdd = 0;
if (minuten >= 0 && minuten <= 29)
{
    minutenToAdd = 30 - minuten;
}
else if (minuten >= 31 && minuten <= 59)
{
    minutenToAdd = 60 - minuten;
}
var MIN_IN_MS = 60000;
var HALF_HOUR_IN_MS = 3600000;

minutenToAdd = minutenToAdd * MIN_IN_MS;
var Datum = moment(jetzt + minutenToAdd).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');





});
</script>
```

Any idea how i can update my query  with "set Testende" with the JS var Datum"?  If you have some question ask it. I try to answer them. Thx for your help.

Comment: Store those values in the hidden input fields and read those value when you make a AJAX request to the server and also send those values with the request.

Comment: Pass the date within `data`(in the AJAX parameters), and read it from `$_GET`..?

Comment: If you are using prepared statements, don't do this: `Datum = '$Testdatum'"`. You are still vulnerable to SQL injections and are making it more complicated for yourself. Use placeholders where the SQL library can replace and escape your values.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi i have no form for hidden input

Comment: @Teemu can u explan more detailed, cant follow right.

Comment: @nkr i changed it with placeholders. thx